# how to dynamically change height of text area jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a text area which gets populated by jquery dynamicaly when a user clicks on a button.

What i would like to happen is once the text area is populated is for the height of it to expand so all the text inside it can be seen?

this is the text area:

```
<textarea type="text" id="notes" name="notes" value="" class="txt" style="width: 97%;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Try the `elastic` textarea plugin: http://unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You better use a jquery plugin for resizing height of the textarea. 
I personally recommend this:
http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize